# Unresolved reference: btn_login for button in MainActivity.kt in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to android studio as well as Kotlin, so here I tried to put some hands on init and encountered some error. I have made a simple program of login but I am not able to use login button.
The error shown is  **Unresolved reference: btn_login**

Here is my MainActivity.kt file

```
package com.example.roomdata

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        btn_login.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this,RegisterActivity::class.java))
        }
    }

}
```

code of activity_main.xml is here described below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Database Login"
        android:textColor="@color/pink"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/pink"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_password" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

code of build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have to bind your variable to a proper id

```
 Button btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
```

after that you can call your

```
 btn_login.setOnClickListener{
        startActivity(Intent(this,RegisterActivity::class.java))
    }
```